# Using .ogg file while with <video> on html5

Tags: html

I am trying to learn web development from w3schools.com
Currently I am studying HTML5 and I had a question on a code which I do not understand. If anyone could help it would be great! :)

In the below code, what is the function of the code 
The code seem to run in the same way even if I delete this code.

Here is the [link](http://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all) where I found this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: *sidenote:* You trust w3schools? oops. Read http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks us to explain code. Also [W3Schools is crap](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: so any suggestions on which the best place to lean html5,css and javascript from if w3schools.com is not good ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 3rd party HTML5 video player library, e.g. [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com) for better support of different formats, browsers, as well as providing Flash player fallback.

Comment: thank you for your quick question! This is my first post on this forum and I seem to be having some trouble posting my question! hahaa... only part of my question has got posted!

Comment: How did you answer this? The OPs question isn't clear. At first it sounds like he's asking where the JS code is for it to work, but then it sounds like he's asking why deleting the code of the left hand screen (without pressing the button to update the right pane) doesn't update the right pane.

Comment: In the below code, what is the function of the code <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
The code seem to run in the same way even if I delete this code.

Below is the link where I found this code: http://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are asking what exactly the

```
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

is doing there and why we got it there...

Just so you can understand this better follow the below steps:

1. Launch Internet Explorer
2. Go at Tools and turn Compatibility View on
3. Visit [the site you mentioned](http://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all) (on IE with Compatibility View on)

You will see you will be getting the message "Your browser does not support the video tag." (because internet explorer with compatibility view on doesn't support HTML5).
If you change that message to the code, this will be reflected to the right of your screen.

Is this a bit more clear now?

Comment: Tanos, thank you for the response. Sorry my code is not getting posted completely... not sure why ..

Answer (score -1):

Video tag `<video>` is an HTML 5 Tag, which is for now supported by very few broswer vendors. The current browser that you are running your code does not support this tag so you are getting this error - "Your browser does not support the video tag.", To cater this you can learn about ["Modernizr"](http://modernizr.com/docs/) is a small JavaScript library that detects the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies, i.e. features that stem from the HTML5 and CSS3 specifications. Many of these features are already implemented in at least one major browser (most of them in two or more), and what Modernizr does is, very simply, tell you whether the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not.

Comment: Incorrect. HTML5 video tag is widely supported by modern browsers. IE is the last to come in to support the tag, but the tag is supported since IE9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: @Shivam - Fyi please review [Can I use Video tag](http://caniuse.com/video), You are right on your comment ONLY latest modern browsers support that too very specific versions, since Spiderweb is a beginner to HTML5, its better to share this with him.

Comment: thank you for the response. Sorry my code is not getting posted completely... not sure why ..this is the code I have             <video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>                                                                   I tried deleting the line that has the .ogg file. This made no difference to the output. You can try on this page http://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all

Comment: @Spiderweb give up w3schools . The tutorials inside maybe incorrect.

Comment: @Spiderweb, W3S has a disclaimer - "Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari support the <video> element.
Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the <video> element."

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, I am only trying to understand what the code <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> is doing here.                                                                w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all

Comment: @Spiderweb - Fallback for HTML5 requires multiple video files
<source src=".MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video 
<source src=".OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10

Comment: Perfect! Now it makes sense... thanks so much! Appreciate your patience! :)